# Controller is not dispatching requested view

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring. After running the program I am receiving error as follows....

> -DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/SpringLoginApp/save]
>   - Matching patterns for request [/save] are [/**]
>   -URI Template variables for request [/save] are {}
>   -Mapping [/save] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler -[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@5771b5fa]
>   and 1 interceptor  -Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin 
>   -Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': -assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 
>   -Successfully completed request

This is my controller where i want to direct...

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)

  public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")EmployeeBean      
   employeeBean,  BindingResult result) 
 {
   Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
   employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
   return "redirect:/add";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView   addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")EmployeeBean employeeBean,BindingResult result)
 {
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("employees",prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
  return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
 }
```

This is my Dispatcher ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">  


 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resource/message.properties"/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springLogin.*" />
   <tx:annotation-driven />
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    id="viewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
  </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    id="dataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${message.driver}"></property>
      <property name="url" value="${message.url}"></property>
      <property name="username" value="${message.user}"></property>
      <property name="password" value="${message.password}"></property>
  </bean>



   <bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springLogin.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    id="hibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
   </bean> 
 </beans
```

This is my form from which the view is requesting...

```
  <form method="POST" action="save" commandName="command">
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Employee ID:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="id" readonly="true"/></td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Employee Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Employee Age:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="age"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Employee Salary:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="salary"/></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
         <td>Employee Address:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="address"/></td>
      < /tr>
         <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
      </tr>
 </table> 
 </form>
```

Pardon me if I'm wrong somewhere... Any help ?

Comment: There is no error that is just debug information .

Comment: @M.Deinum...yeah..but i want to ask why null view is returned...and matching pattern is not returned...though it is there in Controller...Pls help

Comment: The is no matching pattern (that is what the message is telling you)... As stated it is information/debug/trace logging only. Regarding the model it is a redirect that doesn't have a model.